# How do i change my profile picture and display name in physics stack exchange?

Tags: support, profile-page

How do i change my profile picture and display name in physics stack exchange?.i cant see any link in my profile settings

Comment: This meta question seems to belong to the [mother meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as this is not specific to Phys.SE.

Comment: see also [How to change Profile pic](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10169/84967).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a post on Meta Stack Exchange describing [how to change your profile picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar). There are a few different ways to do it, depending on where your profile picture is stored, but in brief:

- If your profile picture is stored on Stack Exchange servers, you go to [your profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/current), click "[Edit Profile & Settings](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current)" then "Change picture"
- If your profile picture is stored on Gravatar servers, you will need to go to [www.gravatar.com](https://www.gravatar.com) and follow their procedure for changing the picture

To change your display name, you simply go to [your profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/current), click "[Edit Profile & Settings](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current)", and enter the new display name in the field labeled "Display Name". There may be [a restriction on how often you can change it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45200/add-warning-when-changing-display-name).

Comment: This can throw some people off - make sure that you're doing this on the user profile on main, and not on meta.